How to read information from a multiple radio interface through libmnl?
I have a Wi-Fi interface that supports multiple (2) radios: the Intel AX210. The libmnl C library allows a program to scan for nearby Access Points (APs). This card has 2 antenna ports, but appears to ifconfig as a single interface. The antennas are physically sitting on a different sides of a metal box.
Examples of using the library include Bartosz Meglicki's wifi-scan project and Robpol86's answer to Using nl80211.h to scan access points.
Is it possible to get information differentiating the 2 ports? In particular, how would one get separate RSSI readings for each antenna?
Additionally, is other potential information available, such as the time delay or angle estimation of the received signal between the 2 radios?

What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want - for example, which language you're using. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].
